# Interactive 3D scatter plot that identifies x,y & z without mouse drag

Tags: r

I have a data frame with observations for x, y and z. I've made this scatter plot using the car package:

```
scatter3d(y ~ x + z, data = mydata,  
     id.method ="identify",
        point.col = "black", surface = FALSE)
```

when I right click drag the mouse over the point I'm interested in, the row number of the observation appears on the plot.

Ideally, I would like a plot where I can run the mouse over each point and have the related x,y and z values appear. Is there a straight-forward way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `plotly` package. A `plotly` 3d scatter plot will show you the x, y, and z coordinates for a given point just by hovering over it with your cursor.

I don't have a sample of your data but the code would look something like this:

```
library(plotly)

plot_ly(mydata, x=x, y=y, z=z, type="scatter3d", mode="markers")
```

You can also include a `color` parameter in the above function if you'd like to color the points based on some factor or numeric value.

Comment: I just tried your code and got a blank image. I also tried the plots in the documentation w/ volcano and economics data and got the same result. Any idea on that?

Comment: Got it, internet was down